# CORS - jQuery get ajax response status failing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, nginx, cors

I'm experiencing a problem with an ajax call to a different subdomain, the request is sent from *www.mydomain.test* to *subdomain1.mydomain.test*. I'd like to handle 4xx and 5xx errors so I can redirect the user.

**When executed from FF or Chromium**, the call works perfectly when the server returns a 200, no CORS problems reported, but when the server returns a 4xx the jqXHR.status property is set to 0 and I get the following CORS message on the console:

```
Failed to load http://subdomain1.mydomain.test/api.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.mydomain.test' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 418.
```

However, **the same call always succeeds when executed with Postman**, even when the server returns a 418 or any other 4xx.

This is the JS code, executed from www.mydomain.test:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://subdomain1.mydomain.test/api.php",
    type : "POST",
    success: function(response)
    {
        redirectToSucessPage();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        console.log(textStatus); //prints out "error"
        console.log(jqXHR.status); //prints out 0

        if(jqXHR.status == 401) //never reached
            redirectToErrorPage();
    }
});
```

This is the full console output:

```
POST http://subdomain1.mydomain.test/api.php 418 ()
Failed to load http://subdomain1.mydomain.test/api.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.mydomain.test' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 418.
error
0
```

The CORS message isn't exactly bothering me, although I'm confused to get it since it only happens with 4xx responses, but I really need the response's status code. The server is returning 418, but jqXHR.status is 0.

This is nginx config of the resource:

```
location = /api.php {                   
    root /path/to/dir;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://www.mydomain.test';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST';

    limit_req   zone=limitZoneOne   burst=5;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

The PHP that produces the response is simply:

```
http_response_code(418) and exit;
```

Am I doing a mistake when getting the response status, or is there some CORS issue with 4xx responses that I'm unaware of? Thanks!

Comment: Need to also allow OPTIONS method and handle the preflight OPTIONS request that must include access control headers before POST is even sent. Read up on how CORS works

Comment: I had tried allowing OPTIONS on nginx before and it made no difference. Do you have any specific suggestion on what the problem may be, or what is lacking in the code/config?

Comment: You just need to specify the `always` parameter in your `add_header` statements. Otherwise, nginx will only add the header if the response code equals 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307, or 308. But if you specify the `always` parameter, the header field will be added regardless of the response code. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks for the tip, I just tried using *always* with add_header but the result is the same. more_set_headers works like a charm, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using more_set_headers on nginx.conf instead of add_header:

```
location = /api.php {                   
    root /path/to/dir;

    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.mydomain.test';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST';

    limit_req   zone=limitZoneOne   burst=5;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Works even without the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header, both on FF and Chromium.

The *more_set_headers* directive is part of the [HttpHeadersMore](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module which is included in the [nginx-extras flavor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553937/what-is-the-difference-between-the-core-full-extras-and-light-packages-for-ngi#556382) of nginx, you can install it on ubuntu 16 by doing:

> sudo apt-get install nginx-extras